# How to query derived object's properties type-safely in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to query a Typescript object to see if it has a property. Code like this:

```js
class Base {
    x: number = 1
}

class DerivedA extends Base {
    y: number = 2
}
class DerivedB extends Base {
    y: number = 3
}
// and many more derived classes...

function f(obj: Base) {
    console.log('x', obj.x)
    if ('y' in obj) {
        console.log('y', obj.y) // ERROR: property 'y' does not exist on type 'never'
    }
}

f(new Base())
f(new DerivedA())
```

(see [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ0PQB4C5oDsBXAWwCMEAnaAXmgEZUBfVVUSGAEUoEsA3BACYBBaAiwAXBPgEx4EJGkzQAnniJlKNaACYmrcFGhcKfQbFESpMuIhTpMqgiXJVaAZj0B6T9DDToxH7KAQD2FEgCPPwC0GxQCBAAdMksAGaE+MDi3CH40KkAFCGkAFZ4cggAlHZKwLkQISAIiSAhAOYFAORYnQA00MUliViV9hjcqdBdyp3Q3HmD1YpKmHX4DU0t7dN9A6WJyqNKzMyohfgIAO428gWVo+dXRlGCQnejQA))

In `f` I'd like to avoid many `instanceof DerivedA || instanceof DerivedB` because there may be many, and I'd forget to add new ones. I'd like to just duck-type it and check for the `y` property. Can I do that in typescript and avoid the error? Do I have to do `(obj as any).y`?

It seems like a bigger question: how can I duck-type an object as a generic derived type of a known base class?

(I'm clearly still learning typescript in case it's not obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is structurally typed so that signature `function f(obj: Base)` is the same as `function f(obj: {x: number})`. i.e. you can call `f({x: 10})` no problem, it doesn't need to actually be an instance of `Base`. Hopefully this helps motivate at least one reason why we can't expect typescript to narrow the type.

Typescript can narrow unions very well and this is the appropriate approach to the problem. We do need to capture "all" the possible argument shapes in the signature but that is easier than a long (and potentially increasing) list like `DerivedA | DerivedB`. Instead we can write the shape like `Base & {y?: number}` or if you prefer, `Base | Base & {y: number}`. Don't treat classes like you would in other OO languages like Java or C#, they behave much differently in the type system here.

`Base & {y?: number}` says the object will have a `x: number` *and* possibly a `y: number` too. Then when narrowing with `'y' in obj`, typescript knows `obj` has the field `y` and the only option is that `'y'` has type `number`, so in the `if` typescript treats `obj` as `Base & {y: number}`. You want to write a signature that covers just what you need in the function body.

Comment: Aha, a little bit more of the light goes on... Thank you!

Comment: Is it just me, or is it weird that with a "union" type in TS you can only use the common members, i.e. their intersection, whereas with an "intersection" type you can use the union of all the members?

Comment: Ha ha when  you write it like that it does sound interesting but it is actually fairly intuitive. If a union is read as "or", then it makes sense that the only properties you can be sure the object has are those that are common all in the union.